# Roman numbering > setcounter to zero > hyperref confused in pdf bookmarks

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, counters, bookmarks

I have the following problem:

For my Master thesis I want to create some sections with a `\Roman` numbering (for toc, lof, lot, appendix...) and some with `\arabic` numbering (for the main text part).
My MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{Abstract}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Acronyms}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{Intro}
\subsection{Part of Intro}

\section{Outro}
\end{document}
```

But this will create wrong bookmarks for the PDF:
[image]

As you can see, `hyperref` creates a `\subsection` for *Acronyms* while this should be a `\section`. I think it's confused, because I reset the section counter and use it again.

The linking is wrong too: If I click on *Outro* I am redirected to *Acronyms*.

So what would be the right way to achieve this?
Thank you a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SE! Select article (scrartcl) is not good idea. Better is select `book` or `scrbook`  which enables logical division of document on `frontmatter` and `mainmater`. Source of your problem is reseting section counter, consequently you in your `mainmatter` repeat section numbering, what confuse `hyperrref`.

Comment: Welcome to Tex SE. Usually the introductory sections have no numbers: List of figures, list of abbreviations/acronyms, abstract, etc... Why are you assigning them a number in the first place?

Comment: @Alenanno: Different university, different countries, different personal styles ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I understand that, but I've read texts from other countries and styles, and I've never seen them numbered. At least as far as I can remember. :P It just sounds non-standard to me.

Comment: @Alenanno: There are worse things being done than to number 'introductory' sections :-P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Using vertical rules in tabulars? Styling sections/chapters manually? Using `\underline{}` in a document? :P

Comment: @Alenanno: Different font colors, font sizes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resetting the `section` number to zero results and using `\section` again results in a second `\section.1` `hyperref` anchor, which **must** confuse `hyperref` and the PDF viewer of course.

The solution is either to use `hypertexnames=false` as an `hyperref` option or to switch to some other anchor name, say `arabicsection`, i.e. redefine `\theHsection` to be `arabicsection.\thesection`.

This cures the `bookmark` levelling problem as well.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{Abstract}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Acronyms}

\renewcommand{\theHsection}{arabicsection.\thesection}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{Intro}
\subsection{Part of Intro}

\section{Outro}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solution works for me too! Is is also possible to continue with the Roman numbering system after the arabic part?

Comment: @Phil: Continue with Roman -> sure. Do you want to continue the numbering as if it has not been interrupted?

Comment: Yes. And I think this shall work: `\renewcommand{\thesection}{section.\thesection}`
right before resetting to arabic

Comment: @Phil: No, `\renewcommand{\theHsection}{section.\thesection}`