# Smallcaps Roman Numbering of Sections

Tags: sectioning, small-caps, roman-numerals

**Is it possible to get section heading numbered with roman smallcaps numerals?**

The minimal working example gives me exactly what I seek, except that I would like the numbering of the Roman Section to be with a **smallcaps numeral**.

For the desired effect, I cannot use `\Roman{section}` instead of `\roman{section}`.

[image: Compiled output of minimal working example]

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Arabic Section}

\renewcommand\thesection{\roman{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{Roman Section}

I vs. \textsc{i}

\end{document}
```

The example is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286272/12558).

Comment: The problem is not small caps of Roman numbers but the bold font version of small caps. That's not widely available, at least not for cm fonts

Comment: When you `\ref` a section, should it print the small-caps version of the section number (something like `\scshape\roman`)? Or should it just print the `\Roman` representation? Also note that there's no **bold** small caps by default.

Comment: I see. I'm using my university's template, which requires that I use the Adobe Garamond Pro font. Compiling with Xelatex, I can produce smallcaps bold with `\textsc{\textbf{i}}`
@Werner: I would prefer the former.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically

`\renewcommand{\thesection}{{\scshape\roman{section}}` will do

for the change of the number itself, note the extra`{}` pair for grouping and limiting the effect of `\scshape`, i.e. the font switching to `small caps`.

The problem is however that both in section headers and ToC entries the section numbers are written with bold fonts.

Normal `cm` fonts do not have a bold version of small caps, but it can be 'enabled/faked/emulated' with `\usepackage{bold-extra}`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{bold-extra}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Arabic Section}

\renewcommand\thesection{{\scshape\roman{section}}}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{Roman Section}

I vs. \textsc{i}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A solution with a very small package, called `scroman`, which defines three new numbering styles:

- `scroman`, which is what you want,
- `osroman` which is like `roman`, except a *final* i is replaced by `j`,
- a similar `scosroman`.

Demo of the first and third styles:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{osroman}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{scosroman}
\tableofcontents
\section{Arabic Section}
\lipsum
\renewcommand\thesection{\scroman{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{Roman Section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code of the small package:

```
\ProvidesPackage{osroman}
%%Provide 3 new numberings : scroman (roman numbering with small caps)
%% osroman (j, ij, iij, iv, v, vj, vij, viij, ix, x & c. )
%% scosroman (mixes scroman and os roman)

    \newcommand{\oldstyleroman}[1]{\expandafter\@oldstyleroman#1\@nil}
    \def\@oldstyleroman#1#2\@nil{%
      \ifcat$\detokenize{#2}$%
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \fi
      {\if#1ij\else#1\fi}% si #2 est vide
      {#1\@oldstyleroman#2\@nil}% si #2 n'est pas vide
    }
    \def\scroman#1{\expandafter\@scroman\csname c@#1\endcsname}
    \def\@scroman#1{{\scshape\romannumeral #1}}
    \def\osroman#1{\expandafter\@osroman\csname c@#1\endcsname}
    \def\@osroman#1{{\oldstyleroman{\romannumeral #1}}}
    \def\scosroman#1{\expandafter\@scosroman\csname c@#1\endcsname}
    \def\@scosroman#1{{\scshape\oldstyleroman{\romannumeral #1}}}
```